# Why compiler can't infer correct type in foreach of Regex.Matches?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, type-inference

I was trying to iterate through a `MatchCollection` from a `Regex` expression within a `foreach` loop, using `var` keyword the compiler infers that chap is an object which gives me an error that `Value` property is unknown.

```
foreach (var chapter in ChapterExtractor.Matches(page.RawContent))
{
    chapter.Add(chapter.Value); // Does not compile!
}
```

when `var` is replaced by `Match` it works perfectly.

```
foreach (Match chapter in ChapterExtractor.Matches(page.RawContent))
{
    chapter.Add(chapter.Value); // OK!
}
```

The example provided at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) also uses the `Match` class in the `foreach` loop.

But, shouldn't the compiler infer that `chapter` is of type `Match` instead of `object`? So, its seems that the compiler implicitly perform a cast from `object` to `Match`. Is that true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But, shouldn't the compiler infer that chap is of type Match instead of object?

`Matches` returns a `MatchCollection` which is not generic, it's enumerator method returns an `object`. So there is no way for the compiler to infer the type.It works when you use `Match` because underlying items are `Match` and that's why it doesn't fail with `InvalidCastException`.

> So, its seems that the compiler implicitly perform a cast from object to Match. Is that true?

Yes it is true.

Answer (score 2):

In a foreach loop, the compiler uses the `IEnumerable` or generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface of the object you're looping. Because the MatchCollection class only has an IEnumerable interface

```
public class MatchCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable
```

the compiler uses

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
```

which in turn gives a Current of type 'object'

```
public interface IEnumerator
{
    object Current { get; }
}
```